# Regular expression problem with ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, greedy

I have a regular expression to match filenames which look like this:

```
name - subname goes here v4 03.txt
name - subname long 03.txt
name - subname v4 #03.txt
```

I want to extract the name and subname, without any addintional data. I'm able to extract the data just fine, the problem that is giving me errors is the `v4` part (it's a version marker which is a v and a digit after it and it's not included everywhere), I want to exclude it but it extracts it along with the subname...

My regex looks like this:

```
^([\w \.]+)(?:-)?([\w \.-]+)? #?\d+
```

I tried doing something like this, but it only works without the `?` at the end of "`(?:v\d+ )?`", and then it can't match filenames without the version:

```
^([\w \.]+)(?:-)?([\w \.-]+)? (?:v\d+ )?#?\d+
```

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

`/^([\w \.]+?) - ([\w \.-]+?)(?: v\d+)? #?\d+/`

I think you need to understand what is the difference of (\w+?) and (\w+)?

Comment: Oh yeah, haven't tried that. I figured the `(?: v\d+)?` should be greedy, not the other part non-greedy. I know the difference, but it was `(\w+)?` because a file may have no subname, that's why both the `-` and the subname regex are with a `?` at the end. Changing `([\w \.-]+)?` to `([\w \.-]+?)?` worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in two stages, first remove the parts that you don't want

```
a = str.sub /\s* (?: v\d+)? \s* \d+ \.[^.]*? $/x, ''
```

And then split the string on ' - '

```
a.split /\s*-\s*/
```